# Show only unique Id's in View ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I'm having a trouble with my view. Currently I'm creating a form. It's a model that has three one to many references and basically stores data from three models. 
[Here's how my form looks](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JbV5F.png)

As you can see the data like commision name and commission description I don't need to duplicate. I need a way in razor code to post only unique data names and description, but the members and positions table should be showed the same way.

I can't find a way, I tried many things but It didn't help.

Here's my Razor View code as of now

```
@model IEnumerable<CPO.Models.CommissionEmployeePosition>
@{
ViewBag.Title = "Index";
Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}


<h2>Commissions</h2>

<p>
@Html.ActionLink("Create New", "Create")
</p>

<table class="table table-bordered table-hover" >
<tr>
    <th>Commission</th>
    <th>Description</th>
    <th>Members</th>
    <th>Positions</th>
    <th>Feedback</th>
    <th>Actions</th>
</tr>
@foreach (var item in Model.OrderBy(m=>m.CommissionId))
{
<tr>
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Commission.Name)
    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Commission.Description)
    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Employee.Name)
    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.EmployeePosition.Name)
    </td>
    <td>
        <p>@Html.ActionLink("List", "Index", "Annotation", new { id = 
item.Commission.Id }, null)</p>
        <p>@Html.ActionLink("New", "Create", "Annotation", new { id = 
item.Commission.Id }, null)</p>
    </td>
    <td>
        <p>@Html.ActionLink("Delete Commission", "Delete", "Commission", new 
{ id = item.Commission.Id }, null)</p>
    </td>
</tr>
}

</table>
```

Any help is highly appreciated. If needed, I can insert my database, how it looks and other things, but as of now I don't think it is needed (I might be highly wrong)

Edit: 
My Action that inserts values to this database

```
foreach (var employee in model.Employees)
                {
                    if (employee.Selected == true)
                    {
                        var commissionemployeeposition = new CommissionEmployeePosition();
                        commissionemployeeposition.CommissionId = commission.Id;
                        commissionemployeeposition.EmployeeId = employee.Id;
                        if (model.SupervisorID == commissionemployeeposition.EmployeeId)
                            commissionemployeeposition.EmployeePositionId = (int)Position.Supervisor;
                        else
                            commissionemployeeposition.EmployeePositionId = (int)Position.Member;

                        //commission.CommissionEmployeePositions.Add(commissionemployeeposition);
                        unitOfWork.CommissionEmployeePositionRepository.Insert(commissionemployeeposition);
                    }
                 }
```

Edit: I added my Model

```
public class CommissionEmployeePosition
{
    public int CommissionId { get; set; }
    public int EmployeeId { get; set; }
    public int EmployeePositionId { get; set; }
    public Commission Commission { get; set; }
    public Employee Employee { get; set; }
    public EmployeePosition EmployeePosition { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Are you sure you gave different commission name and their description for each item in your model?

Comment: Show code of the method which is adding to your table new values

Comment: Declare a variable for `Commission`. In the loop check if `item.Commission.Name` matches `Commission`. If so, omit displaying the value, otherwise display it and reset the value of `Commission`

Comment: there are no different commisions. In the example I showed there is one commision, but it is represented like that because of the many to many relationship with join table. @LabLab

Comment: Can you show how you're getting the data

Comment: getting? I showed how I'm getting, but I added how I'm inserting my data, if you're asking for that @Izzy

Comment: I can't get what you actually want to do with it. Your code works fine, cause there is a lot of members whose have own commission. Try to use `GroupBy` before, to prevent showing same commisions

Comment: @LabLab maybe I explained it poorly. But in the example all the employees are in the same commission. And I just want to display it as one. So this one would not duplicate the Commision Name and Description value. (I'm not sure if I'm explaining it properly, so sorry for that)

Comment: If you are looking for a uniqueness use the hashset for data before it send to the view

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you trying to remove items that have duplicate `Name` and `Description`? That's what I gathered from the question, so sorry if that's incorrect.

You should be able to do something like this in your Razor syntax...

EDIT: Name and Description are of children objects.

```
@foreach (var item in Model.OrderBy(m => m.CommissionId).GroupBy(m => new { m.Commission.Name, m.Commission.Description }).Select(group => group.First()))
```

Comment: in the place {m. Name, m.Description} says that I cannot assign method group to anonymous type property.

Comment: Could you share your model?

Comment: added it in the question, hope it helps.

Comment: Added a slight change since `Name` and `Description` are of child objects. Make sure those properties of `Commission` are `public` and you should be good.